# Replacing pinv with inv in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

Let $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Ax}$ represent a system of equations where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, x\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. However rank of $\mathbf{A}$ is $m-1$. I add another equation $\mathbf{b'x} = y_1$. Then I can get $\mathbf{x}$ as $\mathbf{x}_1 = \left[\mathbf{A};\mathbf{b}\right]^{\dagger}\left[\mathbf{y};y_1\right]$, where, $\left[\mathbf{A};\mathbf{b}\right]$is of rank $m$ and the $\dagger$ indicates pseudo inverse as the matrix is of size $m+1\times m$. Now let us remove the first row of $\left[\mathbf{A};\mathbf{b}\right]$ and write 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}_1 = \left[\mathbf{A}(2:end,:);\mathbf{b}\right]\\
\mathbf{z} = \left[\mathbf{y}(2:end);y_1\right]
\end{equation}
If I calculate $\mathbf{x}_2= \mathbf{A}_1^{-1}\mathbf{z}$, then which of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ will be a more accurate value of $\mathbf{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More accurate in what sense?

Your first method, adding an arbitrary new equation and using the pseudoinverse, gives you a vector whose image under $[{\bf A};{\bf b}]$ is as close as possible (in Euclidean distance) to $[{\bf y}; y_1]$; out of those vectors with that same image, it chooses the one with minimum length.  In general it will not
satisfy any of the system of equations.

Your second method, ignoring the first equation entirely, gives you a 
vector that satisfies all the equations except the first one, but since that first equation was ignored completely, the first entry of ${\bf A} {\bf x}$ could be anything.  The Euclidean distance from $[{\bf A}; {\bf b}] {\bf x}$ to $[{\bf y}; y_1]$ will be at least as great as, and probably greater than, what was 
obtained in the first method.

However, it looks like you don't really care about that new equation you added; 
you might be more concerned with the distance from ${\bf A} {\bf x}$ to ${\bf y}$.  We don't know which method will make this one smaller.

But I don't know why you put that new equation in at all.  Why not use the 
pseudoinverse of $\bf A$ in the first place?

Comment: If I dont add one more equation to $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Ax}$, then $\mathbf{A}$ being rank deficient does not have a unique inverse. And since A is rank deficient, then removing the first row should not alter the actual answer.

Comment: Neither does $[{\bf A};{\bf b}]$ have an inverse.  But both have a pseudoinverse, and pinv is happy to compute it.

Comment: But $\left[\mathbf{A};\mathbf{b}\right]$ will give unique estimate of $\mathbf{x}$, because we'll have as many equations as unknowns. If I dont add new equation, then the system of equations is under determined and will not have a unique answer.

Comment: There's no way around the fact that your system has rank $< n$.  But if you adopt the criterion that you want ${\bf A x}$ to be as close as possible to $\bf y$ and (subject to that) ${\bf x}$ should be as close as possible to $0$, then you do have a unique answer, which is exactly what the pseudoinverse gives you.